# HTTP Url Connection Est. but not opening

Tags: java, http, jsf, url, httpconnection

I've made a connection to a URL.

Using this code :

```
public void ExecURL()
{
    try {
        URL myURL = new URL("http://helpdesk.wi-tribe.net.pk:8080/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa?pid="+projID+"&issuetype="+issueID+"&"+customerField+"="+searchID+"&customfield_10014="+searchMAC+"&customfield_10016="+custMobile+"&reporter="+emailID);
        URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
        myURLConnection.connect();
        System.out.println("connection est: " + myURL.toString() );
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
        // new URL() failed
        // ...
    } catch (IOException e) {   
        // openConnection() failed
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm calling this connection through this `<p:commandLink>` :

```xhtml
<p:commandLink update="@this"
               action = "#{visitBean.ExecURL}" 
               target = "_blank"
               value="Redirect To JIRA"
               process="@this,CustMob,CustID,MacAddr,EmailID"/>
```

Now, I know that the connections been established, but my goal is to open this URL in a new window (Mozilla or Chrome), using the `<p:commandLink>`.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `String` the action method returns, the `commandLink` tag will use as the navigation target. If the action method returns null or void, the current page will be reloaded.

So in order for JSF to go to the URL that is built in `ExecURL()`, you need to return it. The code will need to be something like this:

```
public String ExecURL() {
    return "http://helpdesk.wi-tribe.net.pk:8080/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa?pid=" + projID + "&issuetype=" + issueID + "&" + customerField + "=" + searchID + "&customfield_10014=" + searchMAC + "&customfield_10016=" + custMobile + "&reporter=" + emailID;
}
```

Comment: It still doesnt take me to the URL.

Comment: What happens after you click on the rendered link?